# How to get count of 2nd and 4th Saturday's exactly between 2 dates using sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to get number of 2nd and 4th saturday's 
between 2 dates

Ex:

```
DECLARE @FromDate date='08/01/2016' 
DECLARE @ToDate date='09/20/2016'
```

Please Help me
advance thanks..

Comment: Just a thought.. why you want to do this logic in backend? You can do this in middle tier or upper layer rite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a UDF to create dynamic date ranges, but a Tally/Date Table would do the trick as well

```
with cteBase as (
    Select * 
          ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order by RetVal)
      From [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-08-01','2016-09-20','DD',1) 
      Where DateName(DW,RetVal)='Saturday'
)
Select RetVal From cteBase Where RowNr in (2,4)
```

Returns

```
RetVal
2016-08-13 00:00:00.000
2016-08-27 00:00:00.000
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

> **EDIT to Return Every OTHER Saturday within Range**

```
with cteBase as (
    Select * 
          ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order by RetVal)
      From [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-09-17','2016-10-29','DD',1)
      Where DateName(DW,RetVal)='Saturday'
)
Select RetVal From cteBase Where RowNr % 2 = 0
```

Returns

```
RetVal
2016-09-24 00:00:00.000
2016-10-08 00:00:00.000
2016-10-22 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks : ) @ John Cappelletti

Comment: @ John Cappelletti, its not calculating 2nd and 4th saturdays in Todate

Comment: @Sreevardhan I don't understand.  Give me a moment to review.  What do you mean ToDate?

Comment: @Sreevardhan based on the give date range, the returned values are indeed the 2nd and 4th Saturdays from 8/1.

Comment: [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-09-17','2016-10-29','DD',1)..here it should display 3 saturdays but its giving only 2 saturdays...those 2016-10-08 and
2016-09-24

Comment: @Sreevardhan Your last parameter has an ASCII 63 embedded in it.  Delete you >> ,1 << and retype it.

Comment: @Sreevardhan Are you looking for every other Saturday not just 2 and 4?

Comment: @Sreevardhan Change the final WHERE to >>  Where RowNr % 2 = 0  <<

Comment: @ John Cappelletti , got it...its Okay...Thanks its working

Comment: @Sreevardhan  Never had a doubt.   Cheers.

Comment: @ John Cappelletti -[dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-09-17','2016-11-29','DD',1) if i give like this out put is 2016-09-24 00:00:00.000
2016-10-08 00:00:00.000
2016-10-22 00:00:00.000
2016-11-05 00:00:00.000
2016-11-19 00:00:00.000

Comment: @ John Cappelletti,,there its displaying all saturdays which i dnt need, i am positing my answer

Comment: @ John Cappelletti ,Select RetVal From cteBase Where RowNr in (2,4) this littile fine but between From date and Todate if any 2nd and 4th saturdays are there then in those both months 2nd and 4 th saturdays only should come

Comment: @Sreevardhan I'm still not clear on your requirements.  Modify your questions with a clean example of dates and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You should get in the habit of creating a Calendar table. It will save tons of time if you are processing a lot of gap and island problems based on dates or do a lot of date centric processing. In the mean time, I would suggest that you build up an in memory table for processing your query in the meantime.

```
DECLARE @DATES TABLE
(
    Day INT,
    Month INT,
    Year INT,
    DayInWeek INT,
    WeekInYear INT
    CalendarDate DATETIME
)

DECLARE @FromDate date='08/01/2016' 
DECLARE @ToDate date='09/20/2016' 

WHILE(@FromDate<=@ToDate) BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @DATE DATEPART(DAY,@FromDate....)
   SET @FromDate=DATEADD(DAY,1,@FromDate)
END

    SELECT
      *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
           *
        FROM
           @DATE D
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           (
             ...My Query
           ) MQ ON MQ.Date=D.CalendarDate 
    )AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startDate datetime = '2016-09-16'
declare @endDate datetime = '2016-10-12'
declare @DayName Varchar(20) = 'Saturday'
declare @SelectionType Varchar(20) = '1 And 4'
-- '1 And 4','1 And 3','2 And 4','All' we can pass what ever we want
declare @MothstartDateofStartDate datetime
SELECT @MothstartDateofStartDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @startDate), 0)-1

;with dateRange as
(
  select [Date] = dateadd(dd, 1, @MothstartDateofStartDate), datename(dw,dateadd(dd, 1, @MothstartDateofStartDate)) [DayName]
  where dateadd(dd, 1, @MothstartDateofStartDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, [Date]), datename(dw,dateadd(dd, 1, [Date])) [DayName]
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(dd, 1, [Date]) < @endDate
)
select count(*) from (
select [Date],T0.[DayName],(select count(*) from dateRange T1 
where T1.Date between  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, T0.Date), 0) and T0.Date And T1.[DayName] =T0.[DayName] 
group By T1.[DayName]) PlaceCount
from dateRange T0 where T0.Date >=@startDate ) AA
where AA.[DayName]= @DayName 
and 
'True'=case when @SelectionType ='1 And 4' then case when PlaceCount in(1,4) then 'True' else 'False' end
when @SelectionType ='1 And 3' then case when PlaceCount in(1,3) then 'True' else 'False' end
when @SelectionType ='2 And 4' then case when PlaceCount in(2,4) then 'True' else 'False' end
when @SelectionType ='All' then  'True' end
```